# Random effect quantile regression repeated subjects in SAS

Tags: repeated-measures, sas, random-effects-model, quantile-regression

I want to run a random effect quantile regression with repeated subjects. The subjects bid on two different steaks and I have demographics as explanatory variables.  Can this be done in SAS?

Comment: I don't know much about SAS but did you have a look at [quantreg](http://support.sas.com/rnd/app/papers/quantreg.pdf)?

Answer (score 1):

lqmm and rqpd in R provide approaches for running quantile regression for longitudinal/repeated measures data.
See: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lqmm/index.html and http://rqpd.r-forge.r-project.org/.

Comment: Given that the question simply asks if this can be done, I suppose this should count as an answer. Still, can you expand on this at all? It would be nice to know something about these functions (eg, if one is to be preferred under some circumstances, etch).

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible as of SAS 9.3.  Modeling procedures in SAS that do repeated measure modeling have a `REPEATED` statement.  `PROC QUANTREG` does not have this.  Nor does it have a `RANDOM` statement.

I honestly don't think I've read of any implementation of quantile regression that facilitates the concept of random effects.  But I'd like to know about it!